# Screw Terminal Test Clip

Tags: testing, test-equipment, production-testing

I have a board fitted with a 10-way 3.5mm screw terminal in a similar style to what you see [here](https://www.goosvn.com/uploads/ueditor/file/20180820/6367037229861221754868415.pdf) (GSO14V-3.5):

[image: dimensional drawing from the linked PDF]

I am after a reliable contact to four of these points for testing purposes, without unscrewing and screwing the terminals each time - there are no other test points available on the board. Terminals are pre-screwed in. Currently, four solid wires are used with a rotational force applied to try and force contact - but this has not resulted in a reliable connection thus far.

My initial thoughts are inspired by a pair of C-clip pliers, e.g. an externally contacting test clip - squeeze to pull the halves together, release and they spring apart, then produce a jig to position the four required together. Alternatively, I can envisage a formed wire piece which performs the same external spring function and press fits into the receptacle.

I cannot however find either such product on the market, is anyone aware of such a device in test-clip sized form, or, does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but you can probe the screw itself usually with a multimeter or scope probe. So you could make a 4 headed spring pin probe to contact 4 screws.

Comment: Probing the screw does work providing the terminal is screwed in, I would like a slightly more permanent solution though which can be simply located and left for 30sec or so

Comment: @Sam then why not screw in and out? That sounds easy and quick enough for 30s.

Comment: (But tobalt's spring-loaded probe approach is the professional approach to probing most things; a spring-loaded probe together with some probe holder. There's many ways a probe holder can be built, but the first thing my search engine gave me looks like [this](https://www.probeholder.com/) and I think that well illustrates the idea)

Answer (score 3):

You could build an adapter with spring test probes that make contact to the bottom of the screw terminals.

[image]

[image]

<sub>Source: [www.testprobes.nl](https://www.testprobes.nl/testprobes-testpennen/selecteer-de-juiste-probe/) (not affiliated; we're using a different brand)</sub>

Depending on your budget and the number of devices that need to be tested, this investment could be worth it.

Comment: I had always wondered what these concave head types would be good for ;)